# Can I use the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model with Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: list, client-object-model

Any workarounds or alternatives that work on both SP2010 & 2007.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b4579045-b183-4ed4-bf61-dc2f0deabe47

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Services and CAML are your best bet with MOSS 2007. But having gone through all that pain, If I were to do it again, I would rather take the following approach:

Create a custom web application on the SharePoint server. Create .asmx or wcf services as you see fit. Inside these services you can have object model code.

Things to consider:

1. This might save you time rather than having to get a grasp on the web services and CAML.
2. You can create custom web services directly in SharePoint, but it is again another learning curve, and if you're in a hurry avoid this.
3. It might be worth learning SharePoint 2007 web service methods for future projects, then again a lot of clients are upgrading to MOSS 2010.

Answer (score 6):

No, Client Object Model cannot be used with SharePoint 2007. There are no workarounds.